# IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 cannot handle more than one concurrent connection

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, .net, iis-8.5, mvc

I am in a bizzare situation. Here's my scenario:

[image: Diagram of my application server and data server]

I have been working on an **MVC5 Web API2** Project hosted on **Rackspace** hosting. According to the diagram I've added, the API project is **AppOne**. We have two data sources, one is **MongoDB** hosted in a Linux Server using **MongoDB Driver 1.10.0.62**. Another data source is a **MySQL DB** of the same Rackspace hosting. Now, I have a client app which is **ClientApp** in my diagram. From ClientAPp, I push and pull data using AppOne's APIs. It works perfectly for testing purpose. At this stage I have

- **MongoDB** on **Linux**
- **MySQLDB** on Rackspace
- **AppOne** hosted on **Rackspace** (API Project)
- My Client App named **ClientApp** hosted on **Rackspace**

The above setup works perfectly for me.
The company I've been working for decided to transfer **AppOne(API Project)** to their own windows server. So from now on, I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS8.5 to host the AppOne(API Project). FYI, the windows server is installed with 16gigs RAM & SDDs as storage. So at this stage I have

- **MongoDB** on **Linux(same as before)**
- **MySQLDB** on **Rackspace(same as before)**
- **AppOne** hosted on Windows Server (previously was hosted on
  **Rackspace** and now while connecting to the **MySQL DB** I am using the IPs given by **Rackspace** to connect to **MySQL DB**)

Problem:
At this stage, if I call the APIs from one machine, it works as expected. The APIs supposed to return JSON data and it returns them well. But If I call the APIs more than one PC at the same time, it returns data to only one machine and all others get http 500 error without any error details.

**Please note that, I've changed the request limit to allow infinite in the IIS8.5 management console. But it still the same problem.**

I hope I could describe my problem and please guys if anyone has any idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Enable detailed error mode on the web server.  THis will allow the content and description of the error occuring to filter down the client of the API - see what the error says and it will give you a better clue.

Alternatively, view the Application event log (start run --> eventvwr.msc) and look for Warnings with a source of ASP.NET - error 500s get logged this way on the iis web server - what's the error occuring?

Ensure you have  set in the web.config of the webapi website on IIS - when debug mode is true, it enables server-side recompiles every time a connection is made to the website (thus locking the files from access by any other client connection).